# blogdesigner plugin blog design template issue

Tags: wordpress

In blogdesigner plugin 'standard setting'-> 'Blog Designs' select blog template drop-down values gets automatically reverted after some time.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbIwC.png)